# C - Qsort By Count then Alphabetically

Tags: c, qsort

I'm trying to run a qsort to sort first by number then by alphabetical order. The array words is:

```
COPY 3
CLOSER 2
TAUGHT 2
AW 2
LOOKS 2
SHAD 3
HA 3
```

Struct is:

```
typedef  struct {
    char word[101];
    int freq;
} Word;
```

My compare function so far is:

```
int compare(const void *c1, const void *c2){
    Word *a1 = (Word *)c1;
    Word *b1 = (Word *)c2;
    return (b1->freq - a1->freq);
}
```

And my qsort function is:

```
qsort(words, count, sizeof(Word), compare);
```

but I don't know how to sort it by alphabetical order after I sort it by frequency.

Comment: Richard, your comparison function needs to be more sophisticated. Compare the frequency and the strings...

Comment: If the frequency of the words is the same, then you need to compare the words.  `if (b1->freq != b2->freq) return (b1->freq - b2->freq) else return strcmp(b1->word, b2->word);`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Why don't write answers as answers? you mixed up some variable names there, though.

Comment: Yes, I mixed up the names because the names in the question were inconsistent.  It isn't enough text to be worth converting into an answer, even with the names fixed up.  (Or, if you prefer, "I'm lazy and don't see enough benefit to providing an answer", not least because I'd have to write more to make it an answer I can live with.)

Comment: more for me I guess :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Richard, note a few things here:

1. I do not cast void pointers when assigning to non-void pointers
2. I do not use typedef for the sake of it
3. To get the length of an array, I divide the size of the array by the size of the first element in the array
4. I use `char *` in `struct word`
5. I do not simply subtract frequencies in `compare_words`. To derive the order, I actually use if, else if, else. Simply subtracting integers could have strange behavior depending on the operands.
6. I maintain `const` pointers in my comparison function, to enforce immutability.

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct word {
    char *str;
    int freq;
};

int compare_words(const void *a, const void *b)
{
    const struct word *w1 = a;
    const struct word *w2 = b;

    int order;

    if (w2->freq > w1->freq) {
        order = 1;
    } else if (w2->freq < w1->freq) {
        order = -1;
    } else {
        order = strcmp(w1->str, w2->str);
    }

    return order;
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    struct word mywords[] = {
        { "BAR", 2 },
        { "BAS", 2 },
        { "ACK", 2 },
        { "FOO", 8 },
        { "ZIP", 1 }
    };

    int len = sizeof(mywords) / sizeof(mywords[0]);

    qsort(mywords, len, sizeof(mywords[0]), compare_words);

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        struct word w = mywords[i];
        printf("%s\t%d\n", w.str, w.freq);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
FOO 8
ACK 2
BAR 2
BAS 2
ZIP 1
```